# How long do I need to freeze the freezer bowl when making the second batch of ice cream?

Tags: equipment, ice-cream

I have made one batch of ice cream, and now I need to make another. I have rinsed out the freezer bowl, and when I dried it I noticed that the water had frozen to a thin film of ice. So it is obviously still pretty cold. I am hoping to finish the second batch tonight (at the time of writing it is 7 pm here in Sweden). Is a couple of hours in the freezer enough, or do I need to wait until tomorrow morning?

Comment: Try it. The worst that can happen is you have to melt and re-freeze the next morning.

Comment: Salt and ice rules here (at least in the "not mechanically refrigerated and under $100" class.) Second batch is easy-peasy, no waiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really depends on your freezer and your icecream bowl. Usually the instructions will have a suggested freeze time on them...In my experience, however, it's usually 6-8 hours at a minimum.

If you need to make multiple batches, it is ABSOLUTELY worth your money to get another bowl.

Comment: The goal is to get the whole bowl down to the coldest temperature possible...even though the bowl is at -1 C (it will freeze water) it would be ineffective to freeze more ice cream.  2 bowls is the only reliable way to do two batches, although pre-chilling the ice cream mix in the freezer to near freezing will help.

Comment: @doug: On labor day I saw people try and do two batches, freezing the bowl for 6 hours in between, and the second batch never froze up, not even close. So I agree completely.

Comment: Ok, I guess it will have to wait until tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: It also depends on the ambient temperature and how well-chilled your ice cream is before freezing. You can get away with a lot more if your place is cool and you chill the custard in the freezer to the point of almost starting to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I only had mine in the freezer for 2-4 hours and it worked really well.